# Maven error on using Websockets in JHipster

Tags: java, maven, jhipster, spring-websocket

I am trying to run a project generated using jhipster. I opted to use Spring Websockets while generating the project. However on running the `mvn` command on the folder. I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] diagnostic: C:\java_dev\workspaces\pmilive\pmi\trunk\src\main\java\id\co\allianz\pension\config\WebsocketSecurityConfiguration.java:10: error:
 cannot access org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
public class WebsocketSecurityConfiguration extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
       ^
  class file for org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer not found
[ERROR] error on execute: error during compilation
```

Is there any other additional setting that I should add?

Answer (score 0):

No nothing special is required, I suspect that you had an error during maven dependency resolution phase. maybe something is wrong in your `~/.m2` local repository: try deleting `~/.m2/respository/org/springframework` and re-run mvn.

If you're on Windows, path is `%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository\org\springframework`.